# Can IIS7 execute php files?

Tags: windows, php, iis-7

I have IIS7 on my computer. It can display html files. But if I put a PHP program in the corresponding folder and then try to open it with the Chrome browser I do not see the expected page. Instead Chrome "downloads" this file. Is it beacuse IIS7 cannot display the PHP files?

Answer (score 3):

It can - you'll need to install PHP on your server though.  Try the [Web Platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/Downloads/platform.aspx) as an easy way to add this.